# Csh calls gmt script,boxlocal: Command not found

Tags: linux, bash, csh, gmt

I am running one csh script which invokes gmt script,but then I have problems.
csh script

```
csh  -x x_sect.gmt  0. 300. 0. 800. P1
\cp profile.xy profile1.xy
bbox.csh plt >! plt_P1.ps
```

Relevant part of x_sect.gmt script

```
set center = `boxlocal -l $lon0 $lat0 $angle -c $lonc $latc`
echo $center
set end = `boxlocal -l $lon0 $lat0 $angle -c $lone $late`
echo $end
```

But then

```
set center = `boxlocal -l $lon0 $lat0 $angle -c $lonc $latc`
boxlocal -l -0.1 -30 0 -c 300. 0.
boxlocal: Command not found.
echo
set end = `boxlocal -l $lon0 $lat0 $angle -c $lone $late`
boxlocal -l -0.1 -30 0 -c 800. 0.
boxlocal: Command not found.
```

I have copied `boxlocal` from the bin directory.

```
milenko@milenko-X58-USB3:~/Downloads/Distr70_linux/Projects/Tutorial_Ex3/Gmt_map$ file -i boxlocal
boxlocal: application/x-executable; charset=binary
milenko@milenko-X58-USB3:~/Downloads/Distr70_linux/Projects/Tutorial_Ex3/Gmt_map$ ls -lia boxlocal
58721004 -rwxrwxr-x 1 milenko milenko 13034 Jan 20 14:37 boxlocal
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: if you just need to get this to run one time, add the fullpath before i.e. `set center = \`/path/to/boxlocal ...\`` . Else add it to your path either in the script on in the .cshrc or similar file, Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Yes,this works,thanks.